# Can I store a picture of my grandmother who passed away in my phone, and is it a sin if I cry about her death?

Tags: death, image, technology

Day before yesterday, my grandmother passed away. I love her very much. Among all the grandchild she got, she loved me most. I have few questions:

1. Can I store a picture of her in my phone. She was taking birthday cake from mine.
2. If I cried about her death, will it be count sin for her?

Answer (score 5):

To feel grief when someone has died is totally normal and so it is not a sin to feel sad. However there are things which are haram such as mourning out loud, hitting yourself, ripping your clothes and asking "why?" because then you are questioning Allah's will.

Prophet Muhammad, Peace be upon him, who said: «It is prohibited for a woman who believes in Allah and the day of judgment to mourn any dead person more than three days except her husband four months and ten days» (Reported by Bukhari).

Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “The deceased is tormented in his grave because of the lamentations (wailing) over him.” (Bukhari and Muslim)

The best thing to do is to make du'a.

Answer (score 2):

1. Storing her picture on your phone is ok. What is NOT okay is that you hang a photo on the wall.
2. No, crying about her won't count a sin for her as long as **she didn't tell you to be sad about her death or anything similar**. The Prophet PBUH himself teared when his son Al Kasim died as an infant.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the picture is not exposed (open for anyone to see), you can store her picture in your phone.

Your mourning won't count as a sin, but it may make her soul sad. (Mourning on her grave)
May she be granted Jannah and her punishment be easy on her Ameen!

Comment: May i ask why would it hurt her soul??

Comment: Well, not exactly hurt but she may become sad while she is able to do anything, for example calm you down talk to you that she is fine and in peace.